# Getting id from database and put it in session id

Tags: php, mysql

For my website I need to be able to get an ID from a database after someone logged in. I already figured out how to put the variables from the login page into a session but I cant figure out how to write a code that gets an ID from a database and turns it into a session variable.

```
session_start();
include( "connection.php" );

if(isset($_GET['action']) && ($_GET['action'] == "login")){


  $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["name"]);
  $pass = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, md5( $_POST['pass'] . "90qdjka*@"));    
  $QUERY = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$name' AND password = '$pass' AND enabled = 1";
  $EXEC = mysqli_query($conn, $QUERY );
  

  if(mysqli_num_rows($EXEC)==0){
      
      die( 'Login niet geldig! <a href="login.html">Opnieuw inloggen</a>' );
   }else{
      $_SESSION['name'] = $name;
      $_SESSION['pass'] = $pass;

      $QUERY = "UPDATE users SET lastlogin=NOW() WHERE username = '$name' AND password = '$pass'";
      mysqli_query($conn, $QUERY);
}
}
?>
```

Comment: How to actually get the values out of the database query result set, is something almost any beginner tutorial on the matter should be able to explain to you. If you have not come across the keyword `fetch` yet, then do some research, please.

Comment: From PHP's [md5](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php) manual: "_Warning It is not recommended to use this function to secure passwords, due to the fast nature of this hashing algorithm. See the [Password Hashing FAQ](https://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php#faq.passwords.fasthash) for details and best practices._"

Comment: Your code is open to SQL injection attacks! Please, read [How to prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60496/9193372).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
else{
      if (mysqli_num_rows($EXEC) > 0) {
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($EXEC)) {
               $_SESSION['id'] = $row["id"];
            }
      }

      $_SESSION['name'] = $name;
      $_SESSION['pass'] = $pass;
```

if your query returns only one result then while loop will run only one time but if your query returns more than one record then the last record's id will be stored in your session variable

In $row["id"], id is the column name of the table, if you are selecting all columns from your table and if your users table has columns like name, username, password then you can access it using $row["name"], $row["username"], $row["password"]